# How do I get a list of AD Machines and get the Usernames of the person last logged on effeciently

Tags: powershell

I've been given a task to get A list of machines that include T44, T45, T46, T48 in the name /with the usernames of the last people to log on to them then export them on to and .CSV.

I've been doing it a long way...

Getting a list of the machines -Like "*T44*" then querying against them via `Get-WMI`...

This is what I have:

```
Clear-Host
$T440 = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\khalifam\Desktop\Winver\T440.txt
$Results = foreach ($computer in $T440) {
    # test if the compurer is on-line
    if (!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet)) {
        Write-Warning "Computer '$computer' is off-line."
        # skip this computer and carry on with the next iteration
        continue
    }
    Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $computer –Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select Username, PSComputerName
}
$Results | 
    Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\khalifam\Desktop\T440Names.csv
```

Comment: PLEASE, fix your code formatting. there is a link on the page used to create your post that leads to how to do markdown code formatting.

Comment: does your code produce a valid CSV file? i suspect not - you are using `Formet-Table` and that does not output proper object - it outputs FORMATTING code wrapped around the butchered remnants of your objects.

Comment: your code does not seem complete - the 1st line `Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -Like "LN-T44"' | Select Name` is never assigned or used. would you please post your actual code?

Comment: Thats what i'm not sure of how to join/assign to the script/command

Comment: so ... your actual question only has to do with querying AD for the computer list?